# "A number of positions , ___of which were exactly what he was looking for."

Tags: word-choice

> Mr. A was offered a number of positions in the company, _____ of which were exactly what he was looking for.

1) few
2) both
3) none
4) all

The correct answer for this question is 3 - none.

As for me, of the two answers, none and all, what is more natural for the above sentence is very confusing to me.

Can you explain why the "all" above does not match the answer?

Comment: Yet another English test written by someone who does not speak English.

Answer (score 2):

This is a question not of grammar but of semantics. If you want a fruit, and I offer you the choice of a banana, an apple, and a pear, what are the odds that *all three* of those are "**exactly** what you were looking for"? Pretty slim. So given the choice between "all" and "none", the latter is the likelier option.

Comment: I appreciate your kind advice.

Answer (score 0):

Number 4 is the only grammatically correct sentence.

Number 3 requires *of which was* because *none* is singular.

Number 2 requires *a number of* to be replaced with *two*.

Number 1 is only correct if you insert *a few*.

Comment: See Ngram for [*none of which was* vs. *none of which were*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=none+of+which+were%2Cnone+of+which+was&year_start=1940&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnone%20of%20which%20were%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnone%20of%20which%20was%3B%2Cc0) The "were's" win.

Answer (score 0):

"none" is correct and is more widely used

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=few+of+which+were+exactly%2C+none+of+which+were+exactly%2C+few+of+which+were+exactly&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1600&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnone%20of%20which%20were%20exactly%3B%2Cc0

Comment: You're wrong. I checked your Ngram, you left out "all of which were exactly" here is the link. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=few+of+which+were+exactly%2Cnone+of+which+were+exactly%2Cnone+of+which+was+exactly%2Call+of+which+were+exactly&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnone%20of%20which%20were%20exactly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Call%20of%20which%20were%20exactly%3B%2Cc0